# If area under curve for $f(x)$ is 8 unit$^2$, then find area under curve for $f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, area

Let $f(x): \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is an invertible function such that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$ $\forall x \in [1,5].$ If $f(1)=1$ and $f(5)=5$ and area under the curve $y=f(x)$ on $x$-axis from $x=1$ to $x=5$ is 8 unit$^2$, then find the area bounded by $y=f^{-1}(x)$ on $x$-axis from $x=1$ to $x=5$.

My question here is that as $(1,1)$ and $(5,5)$ also lie on $y=x$, hence when we find $f^{-1}(x)$, then the area bounded by $y=f^{-1}(x)$ on $y$-axis from $y=1$ to $y=5$ will also be $8$ units?

Am I correct?

Comment: I would draw a diagram, mark the areas I know and the areas I am asked about. It should be more or less evident what the answer is.

Comment: If you want to prove it beyond the nice geometrical way you can try to perform a change of variables $t = f(y)$ to the integral $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(t){\rm d}t$ and then do an integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw a picture and try to derive the following formula relating the two integrals in question
$$
bf(b)-af(a)=\int_a^bf(t)dt+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(t)dt
$$